# acces to objects in/out the object tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, object

Is it possible to use CSS/JavaScript on HTML objects in a <object>?
There is a code:

index.html:

```
<object type="text/html" data="1.html"></object>
<div id="bbb"> some content </div>
```

1.html:

```
<div id="aaa">some content</div>
```

And my question is: in "1.html" can I modify by JavaScript #bbb object? And in "index.html" can I modify #aaa object using CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: I recommend not using `object` elements as they are very quirky, this can be accomplished with iframe.

Comment: I know, that I can use iframe with the same effect, but i have listened, that iframe is depracted and can be replaced with object.

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding, `iframe` and `frame` are different things. `frame` is deprecated yes. But not `iframe`, which even has new features in html5

Answer (score 0):

If 1.html is opened by index.html, then in 1.html, you can call 'window.opener' to get a reference to index.html, and thereby access/modify properties inside of it. Likewise, from index.html, you will be able to reference 1.html and modify anything inside of it.

The only requirement is that index.html and 1.html have to be on the same domain. Otherwise, the browser will restrict you from cross-domain access to frames from other domains. So, as long as they are both on the same domain (localhost:8080, example) you will be good.